# What does the "Mastering X-Y" status mean for Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

When viewing your online friends' statuses, you'll see something like below:

```
Level 10 Assassin
Mastering 1-7
```

What does the "Mastering 1-7" mean?

Comment: On the PC anyway, the game status is labelled with the current story mission of the host. Are you on a mission called Mastering right now?

Comment: I doubt that's it because many of my friends playing Zero have that. I think I saw someone playing as another character and their word before the 1-7 was different. Makes me wonder if they missed something in their code and that's like the "world-mission" or something! That's pure speculation though.

Comment: The PC version says "Playing 1-37" etc. I think it is the playthrough (1 is normal, 2 would be Vault Hunter Mode/Game+); and after the dash is the story line mission number. In your case 7, or in the PC example I listed above, 37. This is just a guess though; I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: @Mufasa: I think you're right. Playthrough 1 makes sense, and as I was playing yesterday, sadly I just noticed this, I saw that there are "chapters". I bet that second number is the chapter. Don't know how the word before the 1-N works though...sometimes it's not "Mastering".

Comment: Good idea. But it can't be the Chapter number though, because we're only on Chapter 11 or 12 and the second number is 37.

Comment: Note, this is rather late, but the "Mastering X-Y" is also seen in the PC versions (trying to join a friend's game through Steam wil also show this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Mastering X- Y" you refer to refers to two things.

X will refer to what Playthrough that player is on. Whether it be, 1, 2, or 2.5. 
Y, on the other hand, will refer to what quest of the Main Storyline that player is on. Since there are multiple quests that correspond with each playthrough (including sidequests mind you), these quests are also labelled with numbers.

In your case, "Mastering 1-7" Would refer to Playthrough 1, Hunting the Firehawk.